# General steps for fine-tuning/pre-training a model for an object-detector

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, training-data, object-detection-api

I am facing a similar question as here [[How to Pre-train the Resnet101 for a Faster RCNN in Object Detection API of Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019064/how-to-pre-train-the-resnet101-for-a-faster-rcnn-in-object-detection-api-of-tens/55983229#55983229]).

I use a pre-trained faster R-CNN Resnet101 model and want to fine-tune it with similar data. Currently, I am working with the TF OD API.

Until now, I only run the code here [https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md#running-the-training-job]. However, the accuracy of the validation set is either -1.000 or 0.02% after 10k iterations.

Is the model_main.py function the correct way to fine-tune a model or do I miss a step in between.

Any help/remark/hint is highly appreciated. 
Thanks a lot in advance